# Find and Replace in .txt file by extracting data from spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, regex, vlookup

I need to replace instances like Manhole Name="1" with Manhole Name="SW3/001" for instance by extracting the data from spreadsheet.

Would that be possible using regex, or in any possible way ?

Below is an image of the Excel sheet to extract from, and the .txt file I am working with.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Spreadsheet data to extract from]

[image: .Txt file to work with]

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.

Comment: Unless you provide us with the spreadsheet - we can't write the regex for you.

Comment: I added images of the files...hope these would help.

Comment: You don't seem to have information in either document that relates Manhole Name="1" with Manhole Name="SW3/001". Without a defined link between the 2 names it is impossible.

Comment: The common thing between the two files is the number in the first column. I just need to replace the numbers in the with the correct Name. For instance 'Manhole Name="3317"' would become 'Manhole Name="SW3/80/000"'

Comment: I thought of replacing numbers like 3317 with the corresponding Names, but realised that it could reaplce other unrelated numbers in the txt file